# What is causing my touchstart event to end while I'm still touching the screen, and how can I fix that?

Tags: javascript, html-canvas, touch

**What I'm trying to do:**

I'm trying to add touch controls to games created with the html canvas and JavaScript so that they can be used on mobile / tablet devices.

The controls should simply move a sprite around the game area.

**What I have done so far**

- created a `<p>` element to write the current event to
- created a canvas element
- added `touchstart` & `touchend` event listeners to the canvas element
- created player sprite
- created a game loop to draw each frame and update the player sprite's position
- created a simulation to demonstrate the problems

**What is actually happening**

When I run the game on a mobile device using Firefox 96.2.0 browser, the player sprite's movement is being interrupted and appears to stutter rather than continually accelerating.

When I run the game in Firefox Developer Edition 97.0b6 (64-bit) on PC using 'Responsive Design Mode' and the 'touch simulator' the player sprite moves for about 500ms and stops. The `touchstart` event ends whilst I am still touching the controls and the `touchend` event is fired.

**What I want to happen**

- The player sprite should move and accelerate at a constant rate whilst the control is being touched.
- The sprite should stop moving when the control is released.

**The Simulation**

I have removed the control buttons used in my actual games to minimize the amount and complexity of the code.

Simply touch and hold the canvas element to move the sprite (blue rectangle).
"touchstart" is written to the `<p>` element when the event is fired which is replaced with "touchend" when that event fires.

```js
// function to add touch event listeners
// function to add touch event listeners
function addTouchEvents(e) {
  canvas.addEventListener("touchstart", handleStart, { passive: false });
  canvas.addEventListener("touchend", handleEnd, { passive: false });

  btn.addEventListener("touchstart", handleStart, { passive: false });
  btn.addEventListener("touchend", handleEnd, { passive: false });
}

// the event handlers
function handleStart(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  // get the <p> element
  let log = document.getElementById("log");
  // write to the <p> element
  log.innerText = `touchstart ${e.target}`;
  // write to the console
  console.log(`touchstart ${e}`);

  // set the player's `move` property
  player.move = true;
}
function handleEnd(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  let log = document.getElementById("log");
  log.innerText = `touchend ${e}`;
  console.log(`touchend ${e}`);

  // set the player's move property
  player.move = false;
}

// function to create rectangle sprites
function rectangle(
  width = 64, // sprite width
  height = 64, // sprite height
  fillStyle = "grey", // fill color
  strokeStyle = "none", // line color
  lineWidth = 0, // line width
  x = 0, // the sprite's x position
  y = 0 // the sprite's y position
) {
  // create an object for the function to return
  // assign the function's args to an object called 'o'
  let o = {};
  Object.assign(o, {
    width,
    height,
    fillStyle,
    strokeStyle,
    lineWidth,
    x,
    y,
  });

  // should the sprite be rendered
  o.visible = true;

  // velocity vectors
  o.vx = 0;
  o.vy = 0;

  // return sprite position and size
  o.localBounds = {
    x,
    y,
    width,
    height
  };

  // the rectangle's own render method
  // draws the sprite using the canvas contexts2d commands
  o.render = (ctx) => {
    // setup the styles
    ctx.strokeStyle = o.strokeStyle;
    ctx.fillStyle = o.fillStyle;
    ctx.lineWidth = o.lineWidth;
    // draw the shape
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.rect(-o.width / 2, -o.height / 2, o.width, o.height);
    if (o.strokeStyle !== "none") {
      ctx.stroke();
    }
    if (o.fillStyle !== "none") {
      ctx.fill();
    }
  };

  // push the sprite onto the children array so that
  // we can loop through each object and render each to the screen
  children.push(o);

  // return the object
  return o;
}

// a render function to loop through all the objects in the
// `children` array and use the objects own render function.
function render(canvas, ctx) {
  // clear the canvas
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

  // loop through each sprite object in the `children` array
  children.forEach((sprite) => {
    displaySprite(sprite); // run the `displaySprite` function
  });

  function displaySprite(sprite) {
    // check if the sprite's `visible` property is set to `true`
    if (sprite.visible) {
      ctx.save();

      // move the canvas context2d ready to draw the sprite
      ctx.translate(sprite.x + sprite.width / 2, sprite.y + sprite.height / 2);

      // use the sprite's own render method
      sprite.render(ctx);

      // restore the canvas to its former state
      ctx.restore();
    }
  }
}

// variables shared between functions
let canvas,
  ctx,
  player,
  children = [];

// function to set up the game area and sprites
setup();

function setup() {
  // Create the canvas
  canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
  canvas.width = 512;
  canvas.height = 128;
  canvas.style.border = "4px solid black";
  canvas.style.backgroundColor = "grey";
  document.body.appendChild(canvas);
  ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

  // get the html button
  btn = document.getElementById("btn");

  // run the function to add touch event listeners
  addTouchEvents();

  // create the player
  player = rectangle(
    64, // width
    64, // height
    "darkblue", // fill color
    "darkgrey", // line color
    4, // line width
    canvas.width / 4 - 32, // sprite's X position
    canvas.height / 2 - 32 // sprite's Y position
  );

  // define some props to help move the sprite
  player.vx = 0; // velocity
  player.acceleration = 0.025; // acceleration

  // call the animation loop
  renderLoop();
}

// the animation loop
function renderLoop() {
  requestAnimationFrame(renderLoop);

  // game logics
  if (player.move) {
    player.vx += player.acceleration;
    player.x += player.vx;
  } else {
    player.vx = 0;
  }

  // move the player back to the left of the game area
  // when it disappears on the right
  if (player.x > canvas.width) {
    player.x = -player.width;
  }

  // call the render function to loop through all the objects
  // in the `children` array
  render(canvas, ctx);
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  background-color: rgb(28, 26, 26);
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<button id="btn">Press & Hold</button>
<p id="log">Touch the canvas to move the player</p>
<p>Keep touching the canvas to make the player accelerate</p>
```

So, why is the `touchstart` event ending while the screen is still being touched? If you touch the canvas and then move the pointer (finger / simulated touch) across the canvas the `touchstart` event doesn't end until about 500ms after the pointer stops moving. When moving the pointer, you can see that the sprite gradually accelerates, which is what I want to happen without having to move the pointer.

**Important Note**

Further testing regarding the problems discussed above have shown that the issues only seem to manifest in the **Firefox** family of browsers for **PC** and **Android**.

*If someone would like to verify this I would be very grateful.*

**Other Browsers Tested:**

**PC Windows 10**
Microsoft Edge
Version 97.0.1072.69 (Official build) (64-bit)

Chrome
Version 97.0.4692.99 (Official Build) (64-bit)

AVG Secure Browser (62%)
Version 96.1.13589.112 (Official Build) (64-bit)

**Android 7.0**

Samsung Internet
Version 16.0.6.23

Chrome
97.0.4692.87

**Additions**

Added an `html` button with touch event listeners and handlers.

**Objective:** compare behaviour of button and canvas touch events.

**Result:** same result as touching the canvas. i.e. `touchstart` event ends and `touchend` is fired while still touching the button.

**Update**

I've re-written the test to simplify the code further:

- removed the render function
- removed the rectangle function
- created a stripe using the raw canvas api code in the `loop`
- added some visual cues to show when `touchstart` ends including logs to the console and web page and animation of the stripe
- wrote some logs to the web page as well as the console

**The New Test**

Please use Firefox's touch simulation (ctrl+shift+m and click 'enable touch simulation) to run the tests.

**NB:** *I discovered that you need to reload the web page that the test is running on once you invoke the touch simulation, otherwise, clicking with the mouse does nothing. So, before you run the code snippet, invoke the touch simulation and then reload this web page **(ctrl+r)**.*

```js
// Variables
let start, end, timed, move;

// **** Document Elements **** \\
// canvas
canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
canvas.style.backgroundColor = "#555";

//button
btn = document.getElementById("btn");

// test result targets
btnTest = document.getElementById("btnTest");
canvasTest = document.getElementById("canvasTest");

// **** Listeners **** \\
btn.addEventListener("touchstart", btnStartHandler, { passive: false });
btn.addEventListener("touchend", btnEndHndler, { passive: false });

canvas.addEventListener("touchstart", canvasStartHandler, { passive: false });
canvas.addEventListener("touchend", canvasEndHndler, { passive: false });

// **** Event Handlers **** \\
function btnStartHandler(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  // add a visual cue to the event
  btn.style.backgroundColor = "goldenrod";

  // store the start time
  start = Date.now();

  // write the test results
  console.log(`Button Test: ${e.type} fired at ${start}`);
  btnTest.innerText += ` ${e.type} fired at ${start}\n`;
}

function btnEndHndler(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  // reset the button's color
  btn.style.backgroundColor = "lightgrey";

  //store the end time
  end = Date.now();

  // calculate the duration
  timed = end - start;

  // write the test r
  console.log(`Button Test: ${e.type} fired after ${timed}ms`);
  btnTest.innerText += ` ${e.type} fired after ${timed}ms\n`;
}

function canvasStartHandler(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  //
  move = true;

  // add a visual cue to the event
  canvas.style.backgroundColor = "goldenrod";

  start = Date.now(); // log the time touchstart started
  console.log(`Canvas Test: ${e.type} fired at ${start}`);

  // write the results to the web page
  canvasTest.innerText += ` ${e.type} fired at ${start}\n`;
}

function canvasEndHndler(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  move = false; // animation var
  canvas.style.backgroundColor = "#555";

  end = Date.now();
  timed = end - start; // calc the duration of `touchstart`
  // write to the web page and console
  console.log(`Canvas Test: ${e.type} fired after ${timed}ms`);
  canvasTest.innerText += ` ${e.type} fired after ${timed}ms\n`;
}

// **** Canvas Animation **** \\
// some vars to help us move something on canvas
let x = 0,
  y = 0,
  vx = 1,
  acceleration = 0.25;

// loop so that we can animate something on the canvas
loop();
function loop() {
  requestAnimationFrame(loop);
  canvas.width = document.body.clientWidth;
  // draw a vertical stripe on the canvas
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  ctx.fillStyle = "lightblue";
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.rect(x, y, 16, canvas.height);
  ctx.fill();

  // move and accelerate the stripe while the canvas is being touched
  if (!move) {
    vx = 0;
  } else if (move) {
    if (x <= canvas.width + 16) {
      vx += acceleration;
      // console.log(vx);
      x += vx;
    } else {
      vx = 0;
      x = 0;
    }
  }
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  background-color: rgb(28, 26, 26);
  color: grey;
}
```

```html
<h3>Browser Touch Test</h3>
    <br />
    <p>Touch and hold the button to test</p>
    <button id="btn">Touch & Hold to Test</button>
    <br />
    <br />
    <p>Touch and hold the canvas to test</p>
    <p>
      <canvas id="canvas" width="128" height="64">Canvas not supported</canvas>
    </p>

    <h4>Results:</h4>
    <p id="btnTest">Button Test:</p>
    <p id="canvasTest">Canvas Test:</p>
```

**A Final Note**

Since I originally encountered this problem, I found that *'the problem*' no longer exists in Firefox mobile for Android and my game controls work again :)

I can only conclude from this that *the problem* is a bug with the Firefox touch simulation. Indeed we do have a warning in the console:

`Element.setCapture() is deprecated. Use Element.setPointerCapture() instead. For more help https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/Element/setPointerCapture touch-simulator.js:219:19`

So I'm just hazarding a guess here that they need to update line 219 in their touch-simulator.js and possibly a few other places too :¬/

31/01/2022 Filed a bug report with Mozilla:
https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1752813